# How to delete a repo with egit-github

Tags: github, egit

How do I delete a repo with https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github

I keep getting a `org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.RequestException: Not Found (404)` for the following code:

```
RepositoryService repositoryService = new RepositoryService()
repositoryService.getClient().setOAuth2Token(myOauthAccessToken)
repositoryService.getClient().delete("/repos/myusername/repoId")
```

Based on http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository

Answer (score 0):

“If OAuth is used, the delete_repo scope is required.“

Maybe you need to set this somewhere?